# I want to show a image first then I want to show the site content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a page named a.html and a picture x.
Now, when users go to a.html, I want to show the picture x for 3/4s then I want to show the page content.
Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? it will help giving some code and are you planning on using any libraries?

Comment: No I didn't tried anything. I'm not going to use any libraries. I want to make it with simple JS. If you can help me. plaese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small code that will use pure js to show a image prior to showing the content of the site. I think this is similar to what people use to show a loading image before loading the content.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image before loading content</title>
</head>
<body onload="show();">
    <div id = "myDiv">
        <img id = "myImage" src = "http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading45.gif">
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: none;"> 
        This is a CONTENT SECTION Put your content here
    </div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
        setTimeout("hide()", 5000); // 5 wait, change the delay here
    }

    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display="block";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This yo can put in a HTML page and you shold be able to see where i made the image and where the delay time will be happening.

Here is a working example using the above code: https://jsbin.com/pixemiwubu/edit?html,output

Comment: Let me know if its working and you can tweak it abit where needed. Please  approve the answer if its working :). Good Luck!